# Rotating an object around a point with the left or right side to the center in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As planned, the plane should fly along a given route (there are no problems here). Further, he should deviate to a given point and begin to circle around it. This is where the problems began. If this is done using RotateAround, then the plane flies different sides forward (depending on which side of the screen it flies). Help! =)

```
transform.RotateAround(point, Vector3.forward, 45 * Time.deltaTime);
```

[image]

RotateAround works counterclockwise by default. If the plane is near the point in this position, then it flies correctly - with the left wing to the center.
[image]

If so, it flies backwards forward. Sorry for my English )

[image]

If so, or from below, then flies sideways forward.

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to make an object rotate around another object? Sort of like how earth is orbiting the sun?

Comment: I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Further, he should deviate to a given point and begin to circle around it.

Maybe you can try checking for a condition and call `Rotate()` where `centerPoint` is the position you want your gameobject to orbit around.

> If this is done using RotateAround, then the plane flies different sides forward (depending on which side of the screen it flies). Help! =)

I believe setting `rotateClockwise` to either true or false will solve this part of your problem.

```
public float xSpread;
public float zSpread;
public float yOffset;
public Transform centerPoint;

public float rotSpeed;
public bool rotateClockwise;

float timer = 0;
    
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    timer += Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed;
    Rotate();       
}

void Rotate() {
    if(rotateClockwise) {
        float x = -Mathf.Cos(timer) * xSpread;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(timer) * zSpread;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, yOffset, z);
        transform.position = pos + centerPoint.position;
    } else {
        float x = Mathf.Cos(timer) * xSpread;
        float z = Mathf.Sin(timer) * zSpread;
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x, yOffset, z);
        transform.position = pos + centerPoint.position;
    }
}
```